# error at SQL recursive level using MSDAORA on excel 2010 using OLEDB

Tags: sql, database, excel, oracle, oledb

I´a using a MSDAORA (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle ) on excel 2010 to retrieve a view from a oracle database, was working fine until yesterday, begin throw it a error message **ora-00604 error occurred at recursive sql level**

I dont have any clue where to check. 
 - My conection to the BD is via a VPN.
 - Excluding the excel, the connection to the database works, the systems that work with the DB works.

[Screen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC6qe.png)

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle) for ages. Try to use the **Oracle Provider for OLE DB**, you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many reasons of that.

1- Table or view, or mostly trigger does not exist anymore. Make sure your view still exists. A possible cause for recursive SQL errors is also a trigger.

To make sure it is not a trigger-related error,you may try executing this lines:

```
Alter system set “_system_trig_enabled”=FALSE;
SELECT * FROM dba_triggers
WHERE trigger_type not in (‘before each row’,’after each row’)
```

2- Another common example is to try to run a table or view that has been newly created. Here, you need to recombile DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH package by using SYS until no invalid package is viewed.

If both does not work, you should check spelling and debug your code line by line. If nothing works, try to contact your DB admin. Good luck.

Ref: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4018285967344

Ref2: https://www.tekstream.com/oracle-error-messages/ora-00604-error-at-recursive-sql-level-1/

Comment: I don't think it is a good approach to start with modifying an undocumented Oracle parameter. Most likely the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I had to talk to the admin DB, it seems to have something to do with the users, the admin user has no problems.